# JSP page with dynamic html

Tags: java, jsp

I've been trying to write a website in which all navigation is handled by hiding and showing divs. It is my understanding that this method is called Single Page Interface. This has worked for simple designs in the past but my current task is starting to become very troublesome using this method. How would I go about replicating the same behavior but instead of hiding and showing divs I can just have a main container div that is then populated with the desired html from the server?

Example:

```
<script>
    $("#button").onclick(function() {
        $("#a").show();
        $("#b").hide();
    });
</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="a" style="display:none;">A: SOME HTML</div>
        <div id="b" style="display:block;">B: SOME HTML</div>
        <button id="button">Change to A</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

(note this is a very rough example of white I'm trying to do)

But I would like the contents of a container div to change from "B" to "A" via some jsp

Could anybody point in the correct direction?

Further Explanation:

Maybe I can clarify a little better. So when the user loads the page they are presented with a section that has a table of all the existing files in a database. The user can select a file from the DB list to rename or copy. If the user wishes to rename a file, for example, they would be presented with a new display (all within the same "Tab") which will have a set of fields populated for the file that they have selected and a set of empty fields in which they can specify the new file name. Currently this changing of displays is handled by showing and hiding divs, but I would like to retrieve the html that I want to display from the server and present it. Basically mimicking the hiding and showing of divs.

Comment: to understand it better - do u mean tabbed elements - for example : http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Well the interface that I'm trying to develop does involve tabbed elements. But within each tab there are various different tasks one could accomplish. For example under one tab a user could upload, rename, or copy a file. Under another tab one could edit various settings etc. But the tabs are not the issue, its the content within each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not completely clear to me what you're trying to do I'll give you some options:

1. Replace the content of a element on your page see
2. Since you're using a JSP, you can use server side logic to display certain fragments
3. You're using a JSP, use that to render some server side content

Ad 1:

(assuming jQuery) `$('body').load('serverSide.html');` see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Ad 2:

```
<% if ("a".equals(request.getParameter("aOrB"))) { %>
<jsp:include page="/a.jspf">
<% } else { %>
<jsp:include page="/b.jspf">
<% } %}
```

Ad 3:

```
<%= request.getAttribute('content') %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: So say I have a chunk of html I wish to display in a div stored on the server. Can I specify $("#targetDiv").load("desired.html"); and have the html from "desired.html" displayed in "targetDiv" all formatted and whatnot?

Comment: THANK YOU! That works great. This combined with history.pushstate() is exactly what I've been looking for.